# Get product of two one dimensional array in python

Tags: python, numpy

Something very simple in Matlab, but I can't get it in Python. How to get the following:

```
x=np.array([1,2,3])
y=np.array([4,5,6,7])

z=x.T*y
z= 
[[4,5,6,7],
[8,10,12,14],
[12,15,18,21]]
```

As in

```
 x [4][5][6][7]
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In scientific python that would be an outer product `np.outer(x,y)`

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html:

```
import numpy;
>>> x=numpy.array([1,2,3])
>>> y=numpy.array([4,5,6,7])
>>> numpy.outer(x,y)
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [12, 15, 18, 21]])
```

Answer (score 3):

In MATLAB, `size(x)` is `(1,3)`.  So `x'` is `(3,1)`.  Multiply that by `y`, which is `(1,4)`, produces `(3,4)` shape.

In `numpy`, `x.shape` is `(3,)`.  `x.T` is the same.  So to get the same outer product, you need to expand the dimensions of `x` and `y`.  One way is with `reshape`.

```
z = x.reshape(3,1)* y.reshape(1,4)
```

`numpy` also lets you do this with a `newaxis` indexing (`None` also works).  It also automatically adds beginning `newaxis` if that is needed.  So this also does the job:

```
z = x[:,np.newaxis]*y
```

`np.outer` does exactly this (with a minor embelishment): `a.ravel()[:, newaxis]*b.ravel()[newaxis,:]`.

---

There's another tool in `numpy`

```
z = np.einsum('i,j->ij',x,y)
```

It is based on an indexing notation that is popular in physics, and is especially useful in writing more complicated inner (dot) products.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6, 7]
z = [[i * j for j in y] for i in x]
```